# Pydeck layer not rendering, only map

Tags: python, streamlit, pydeck

I am a beginner and trying to visualize some data with Pydeck. My problem is, it only shows the background map and no data. I would like to visualize the prices of the Air BnBs in Berlin.

Maybe someone can help? Thanks!

The data is retrieved from:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/lennarthaupts/airbnb-prices-in-berlin/data

```
import streamlit as st
import pydeck as pdk

st.title("Air BnB Berlin 07/2021")


#data
in_csv = "listings_berlin.csv"


#layer
layer1 = pdk.Layer(
    'ColumnLayer', 
    in_csv,
    get_position=['longitude', 'latitude'],
    auto_highlight=True,
    elevation_scale=50,
    pickable=True,
    elevation_range=[0, 3000],
    extruded=True,
    coverage=1)


# Set viewport location to Berlin
view_state = pdk.ViewState(
    longitude=13.4,
    latitude=52.5,
    zoom=6,
    min_zoom=5,
    max_zoom=15,
    pitch=40.5,
    bearing=-27.36)

# render
air = pdk.Deck(layers=[layer1], initial_view_state=view_state)
air
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

About the data:

For some reason the download link on the [Kaggle website](https://www.kaggle.com/code/lennarthaupts/airbnb-prices-in-berlin/input) was unresponsive.

I looked for the data and found it on the [inside AirBNB website](http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data/).

Looks like there are some NaNs which causes the script to fail.

I created a new `csv` file with just part of the coordinates to test my code.

```
import streamlit as st
import pydeck as pdk
import pandas as pd

#data
in_csv = "part1.csv"

listings_df = pd.read_csv(in_csv)


st.pydeck_chart(
    pdk.Deck(
        map_style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9",
        initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
        latitude=52.5,
        longitude=13.4,
        zoom=10
        ),
        layers=[
            pdk.Layer(
                "ScatterplotLayer",
                data=listings_df,
                get_position=["longitude", "latitude"],
                get_color=[200,20,20],
                get_radius=120
            )
        ],
    )
)
```

This is the map with some of the listings in red.

[image]